# Game Center new match invite automatically and immediately declined by invitee

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit, gkturnbasedmatch

I have a Game Center/GameKit iOS app (Swift2 iOS9) that uses GKTurnBasedMatch. I am having a problem with only a subset of online GC friends, where new matches to them are immediately declined. This is not done by the friend but somehow it is happening automatically. With other friends, the match is received and continues just fine.

What are the conditions (proper and corrupt) where Game Center will automatically decline a new match?

Comment: You could turn on logging in the developer section in the game center settings and then export the logs. Maybe you see something in the logs. (I'm "learning" game center currently and nothing works when I try to invite friends in the sandbox - my question for that is here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33146697/1396265 ) Maybe the issues are related.

Comment: You said you were using ios9. can you confirm which ios version the affected users are running? Also, is this a fully released game? Or a test build?

Comment: iOS 9.02. It is not released. It is a test build. I think I know what may be going on.  When my version on my device is build N and my beta testers have build N-1 (or less), the new games are automatically rejected. Oddly, all other functions, like sending turns for established games, appear to work. I *think* this is the issue but am still working to fully confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem occurs when you are testing and your build is newer than your invitee's build. Interestingly, persons with lower build numbers are still able to successfully start matches with persons with higher ones.

Comment: Hi! Have you reported this issue to Apple?

Comment: I think I did, but forgive me for not remembering with certainty. The good news is that I don't seem to be having the issue anymore.